# filesystem abstraction in python

Tags: python, filesystems

I'm looking for a filesystem abstraction to read and store files just as php [gaufrette](https://github.com/KnpLabs/Gaufrette#gaufrette) library.

Goal is to access files the same way wether it is on FTP, local filesystem, GridFS, depending on environment. Is there any already ? what would be the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to look at pyfs. It doesn't support GridFS, but it does support a lot of backends and it would be easy to add more.

http://code.google.com/p/pyfilesystem/

http://packages.python.org/fs/

Comment: thanks, it seems to be exactly what i'm looking for